# LG Spectrum Jumping To Home Screen

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I've got a problem with my LG Spectrum.  I've had it about 3 or 4 weeks now.  It keeps jumping to the home screen.  In other words, whatever app I'm looking at or have open, it will just exit to the home screen.  It's an intermittent problem.  It doesn't happen all the time, but when it does it will often happen several times over and over again.  It exits, I go back into the app.  It exits again a second later.  I go back into the app, etc.

I haven't been able to find any particular pattern to it.  It can happen in any application.  It can happen while I'm typing, swiping or just looking at something.  It can happen if the phone has been on for hours, or if the phone was just barely turned on and I'm in my first application.  It never shows my any error whatsoever.  However, about 25% of the time I will see for a brief flash the Car Mode screen popup or the Car Mode icon appear on the status bar at the top.  So, I'm guessing it has something to do with the Car Mode being activated inadvertantly/incorrectly, but I'm not even sure how the phone decides it's time to start Car Mode yet.  Every other phone I've ever had you started Car Mode manually.

The phone is not rooted and the latest OTA updates have been applied.

Firmware: VS920ZV4

MUC 6.2.0.3_B013_6

Comment: Do you have a screen protector on it? That can sometimes cause the hard buttons to activate. Or has something happened that may have damaged your charging port? The phone determines when to start car mode by a certain jumper connection in in the cable.

Comment: The phone activates car mode during normal operation whether the cable is connected or not.  All I have to do is stick it in the winshield mount and car mode comes on.  And no, it doesn't have any screen protectors on.

Comment: possibly related: [Screen goes back to home screen frequently, after Data Network enable](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28407/16575)