# Screen goes back to home screen frequently, after Data Network enable

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-plus

When I enable Data Network, my phone goes back to home screen frequently whenever I use another application or go to another place. Even when I close my screen, my home screen appears. How to fix this error? When i deactivate the data network mode, the phone works normally.. please please please update me the solution on it.

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S plus.
Model Number - GT-I9001
Firmware version - 2.3.6

Answer (score 1):

Same phone. Never had this happen to me.
Using a custom ROM though. BroodROM Business Edition.
I would recommend upgrading your system or flashing a custom ROM.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of WakeLocks. You can use 'Phantom key press manager' to avoid wakelocks. My i9001 is working like a gem after installing the application.